# Why can my new user login as sysdba in oracle?

Tags: oracle, schema, sys, sysdba

I just installed Oracle 11g R2 on windows 7 machine. I am able to login using my sys as sysdba account.

Using the sys account I created a user as follows

```
create user testuser identified by testuser;
```

When I try to connect to database with testuser as Normal user it says that 'user testuser lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied' which is understandable since I have not granted any permissions so far to testuser.

But when I try to login to database using testuser as sysdba, it allows me to connect to database and the selected schema seems to me as SYS schema.

Is there something I am missing because I think user testuser should not be able to even login let alone login to SYS schema. I have also found that I can connect as sysdba with any username regardless of if it is present in the database.

How can I create a regular oracle user which does not have access to any other schema?

Answer (score 3):

Your windows user is part of the dba group (*oradba*). It uses Windows authentification to connect `as sysdba`. See [this thread on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:52261686418590):

> "as sysdba" is extremely powerful, it uses OS AUTHENTICATION, it does
>   not require  database authentication (it is used to login before there
>   is a "database" or even an  "instance"!)

As a member of the dba group, you can login `as sysdba` with any database user. You can even login without a user: `sqlplus / as sysdba`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would normally create a new user:

create user &1
  identified by &2
  default tablespace &3
  temporary tablespace &4;

grant connect, resource to &1;
grant alter session to &1;

** get the picture; also include other default privileges like "create ... " : sequence, synonym, table, view, database link select_catalog_role etc.